# Django фильр товаров по цене

Tags: django, интернет-магазин, фильтры

Имеется вот такой кусок из шаблона интернет магазина скачанного с интеренета :

```
    <div class="price-range"><!--price-range-->
      <h2>Price Range</h2>
      <div class="well text-center">
         <input type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="600" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[250,450]" id="sl2" ><br />
         <b class="pull-left">$ 0</b> <b class="pull-right">$ 600</b>
      </div>
    </div><!--/price-range-->
```

это ползунок с регулеровкой цены. Как я могу это переписать что бы djangо воспринимал это как фильтр для цены в интернет магазине. Какие способы для этого есть вообще? Любая ссылка поможет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание на параметры data-slider, они задают то, как ползунок бегает. Далее можно брать значения при помощи js этом сладере должна быть функция как взять из него значение. Если получили значение, то его можно добавить в html форму, которую отправить уже по кнопке submit на сервер или можно использовать ajax